# Fire a jquery loop to iterate before animation callback is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fadein, sequential

I am trying to make a sequential animation, where a loop iterates through a list of elements `.post`'s and fades them in slow. The difficult part is having it so that the next iteration begins fading in before the last one has finished fading. All I have so far is a simple sequential animator that fades them in one after the other.

```
$(".post").hide();
var posts = $(".post"),
    i = 0;
(function() {
  $(posts[i++]).fadeIn('slow', arguments.callee);
})();
```

Does anyone know how I could change this to allow `.post` to fadeIn() before the previous elem/s have finished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over them using `each()` and use a `setTimeout()` for each one, multiplying the duration of the animation by the current `index` in the each.

```
var posts = $(".post").hide();

  // Holds reference to the index of the current iteration
  // ------------------v
posts.each(function( index ) {
    var $th = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $th.fadeIn('slow');   // Removed arguments.callee
    }, index * 300);
});
```

So each `setTimeout()` will have a duration of `n*600`, which should give you the effect you want.

*By the way, if you don't need the `posts` variable for any other purpose, you can eliminate it and chain the `.each()` after the `.hide()`, as in `$(".post").hide().each(func...)`*

---

**EDIT:** I had an error. I was using `this` inside the `setTimeout()` which has a different value. Edited to pass in the correct value.

**EDIT:** Mis-read the question. Changed the duration of `setTimeout()` to `300` to give a partial overlap in the animations.

Comment: Excuse my daftness. I'm not exceptional with jquery. But this returns 'too much recursion'. And I'm not quite sure even where to begin deciphering how

Comment: @Trip - Not sure why you would get that, but see my update. I had an error in the code.

Comment: @Trip - Also, make sure you're not already in a loop, if there's more code than is shown in your question. And I'm not sure what the purpose of `arguments.callee` is. You may want to remove that.

Comment: Awesome, it works, i was just dumb ( as usual ). For it to be obvious, I changed the fadeIn(1500), and the index * 300

Comment: @Trip - Here's an example that shows it in action. http://jsfiddle.net/rbyN6/ I would need to see more of your code to see what is wrong. And I'm not sure what you mean by *"before the last one is finished"*. I thought you wanted them to be sequential. Are you saying you want them to be simultaneous? Or partially overlapping?

Comment: @Trip - Ok, I see. You wanted the partial overlap. Yep, changing the duration would do it. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to patrick's solution, but a little cleaner in my opinion

```
(function() {
  $(".post").hide().each(function(index){
    $(this).delay(index * 300).fadeIn('slow');
  });
})();
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/ojoki4/), the `300` is the duration of the delay where as the `'slow'` is the duration of the fade

Comment: Ah yes, it does work, I realized that after changing the params to make it a more obvious tween.